# Blazor MailKit Email Template

Tags: c#, html-email, blazor-server-side, mailkit

I have a Calculator and i use the following to send the results by email

```
    public void SendEmail()
    {

        emailbody = "<i>Dear,&nbsp;" + model.FullName;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br>";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><i>Here are the results using Dromon's Bureau of Shipping EEXI Calulator for:&nbsp;" + model.VesselName + "&nbsp;with IMO Number:&nbsp;</i>" + model.IMONumber;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><br>";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<hr>";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Full Name:&nbsp;</b>" + model.FullName;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Email Adsress:&nbsp;</b>" + model.EmailAddress;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>ISM Manager:&nbsp;</b>" + model.ISMManager;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Vessel Name:&nbsp;</b>" + model.VesselName;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>IMO Number:&nbsp;</b>" + model.IMONumber;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Type of Vessel:&nbsp;</b>" + model.TypeOfVessel;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Gross Tonnage:&nbsp;</b>" + model.GrossTonnage;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Year of built:&nbsp;</b>" + model.YearOfBuilt;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br>";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Dame and time of Calculation:&nbsp;</b>" + @DateTime.Now;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>EEXI Value:&nbsp;</b>" + eexi;
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><b>Compliance with EEXI regulation:&nbsp;</b>" + Convert.ToString(model.Compliance);
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><br>";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<hr>";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><i>Thank you for using Dromon's Bureau of Shipping EEXI Calculator.";
        emailbody = emailbody + "<br><small>This message was sent from an unmonitored address. Please do not respond to this message. Send all inquiries to it@dromon.com";
        
        email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("******"));

        email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(model.EmailAddress));

        email.Bcc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("******"));
        email.Subject = "Dromon Bureau of Shipping EEXI calculation Results for IMO Number:&nbsp;" + model.IMONumber;
        email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = emailbody };

        using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Connect("mail.******.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        smtp.Authenticate("******", "******");

        smtp.Send(email);
        smtp.Disconnect(true);

    }
}
```

And the result email is:

[image]

Now I would like to make the email body an HTML template so it looks more professional and binds the model values similar to what I have now. Please note that I cannot bind values on another page.

Comment: Have you seen this article?: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-email-using-templates-in-asp-net-core-applications/

Comment: It already is HTML. THat's what `<br>` and `<hr>` are. Are you asking for a pretty design?